# Map of generic functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've got a `Message` interface that takes a generic argument `T` and sets the value of `T` to be the type of an internal property called `body`:

```js
interface Message<T> {
  body: T
}
```

I also have an `EventHandler` interface that describes a generic function that takes a `Message` as it's sole parameter:

```js
interface EventHandler<T> {
  (event: Message<T>): void
}
```

Finally, I have an `Integration` class that has a `subscribe` method and a `subscriptions` map that both look like the following:

```js
class Integration {
  public subscriptions: new Map<string, EventHandler>()
  protected subscribe<T>(eventName: string, handler: EventHandler<T>) {
    this.subscriptions.set(eventName, handler)
  }
}
```

Ultimately, I want the user to be able to define their own `Integration` instances like this:

```
interface MyEventProperties {
  foo: string
}

class MyIntegration extends Integration {
   constructor() {
     super()
     this.subscribe('My Event Name', this.myEventHandler)
   }
   myEventHandler(event: Message<MyEventProperties>) {
     // do something
   }
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. Because I don't know the generic type that ALL `EventHandler` functions will be getting I can't define the second generic parameter when instantiating the `Map`:

```
class Integration {
  public subscriptions: new Map<string, EventHandler>()
  // This errors with: Generic type 'EventHandler<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

  protected subscribe<T>(eventName: string, handler: EventHandler<T>) {
    this.subscriptions.set(eventName, handler)
  }
}
```

My question is, am I approaching this problem incorrectly or am I missing something more obvious?

Comment: Create a base class for `EventHandler` that doesn't have a generic type argument. Use this in your `subscriptions` collection and `EventHandler<T>` in the public `subscribe` method.

Comment: another possibility is to default the generic to "never" or "unknown" in EventHandler so its no longer REQUIRED that it be passed in, i only skim read this article though.

interface EventHandler<T = unknown>

Comment: @AndyLamb - so are you saying that the `Map` constructor look like this? `new Map<string, (event: any) => void>()` (where it can accept any argument as a parameter)?

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to use `unknown` as the generic parameter in the map. The below solution will work:

```
interface Message<T> {
    body: T
}
interface EventHandler<T> {
    (event: Message<T>): void
}

class Integration {
    public subscriptions = new Map<string, EventHandler<unknown>>()
    protected subscribe<T>(eventName: string, handler: EventHandler<T>) {
        this.subscriptions.set(eventName, handler)
    }
    public publishEvent<T>(eventName: string, msg: Message<T>) {
        (this.subscriptions.get(eventName) as EventHandler<T>)(msg);
    }
}

interface MyEventProperties { foo: string }
class MyIntegration extends Integration {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.subscribe('My Event Name', this.myEventHandler)
        this.subscribe('My Event Name Mistaken', this.myEventHandler) // no relation between name and event 
    }
    myEventHandler(event: Message<MyEventProperties>) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The problem though is there is no relation between the event name and the type of the event. This may be a problem both when subscribing (as highlighted above) but also when emitting the event (the message body would not be checked against the expected message type)

I would suggest adding an mapping type between event type and name:

```
interface Message<T> {
    body: T
}
interface EventHandler<T> {
    (event: Message<T>): void
}

class Integration<TEvents> {
    public subscriptions = new Map<PropertyKey, EventHandler<unknown>>()
    protected subscribe<K extends keyof TEvents>(eventName: K, handler: EventHandler<TEvents[K]>) {
        this.subscriptions.set(eventName, handler)
    }
    public publishEvent<K extends keyof TEvents>(eventName: K, msg: Message<TEvents[K]>) {
        (this.subscriptions.get(eventName) as EventHandler<TEvents[K]>)(msg);
    }
}

interface MyEventProperties { foo: string }

class MyIntegration extends Integration<{
    'My Event Name': MyEventProperties
}> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.subscribe('My Event Name', this.myEventHandler)
        this.subscribe('My Event Name Mistaken', this.myEventHandler) // error now
        this.subscribe('My Event Name', (e: Message<string>) => { }) // error, type of body not ok  
    }
    myEventHandler(event: Message<MyEventProperties>) {
        // do something
    }
}

let m = new MyIntegration();
m.publishEvent("My Event Name", 0) // error body not ok 
m.publishEvent("My Event Name M") // error mistaken name
m.publishEvent("My Event Name", {
    body: { foo: ""}
}) // ok message and body correct
```

Comment: Thanks you Titian! This is super helpful. I have something similar to the `TEvents` interface you've laid out so I'm good there. One remaining issue though is I'm trying to enforce that the generic argument in `Message` extends another specific type. So the declaration looks like this `interface Message<T extends Foo> {}`. 

I think that makes it impossible to define `EventHandler` as `EventHandler<unknown>` right? I suppose it's possible though to do `EventHandler<T extends Foo | unknown>`